# WinGroove high CPU usage

Tags: audio, midi

I have a copy of WinGroove 0.9E, but when the output to WinGrooveDirect, the CPU usage goes to 37%, and even 48%, and the audio lags out. The overall CPU usage is near 100%. How do I solve this? This software was for ~WInNT 5.0.
OS: Windows 10 20H2
Hardware: HP Laptop 15t-dy100
CPU: Intel Core i5 Gen 10
Additional specs: https://laptoping.com/specs/product/hp-15t-dy100

Comment: Why do you think that's a "high CPU usage"? High compared to what? Anyway, please add hardware specification and OS version

Comment: Please always add requested information to the question itself, not comments. Please note I'm not answering this, just informing about HOW to ask properly and hardware specs and OS is the bare minimum. Now, have you considered it's a freaking old software that might not be optimized for any OS newer than freaking Windows 2000?

Comment: Still missing the hardware specs, kinda important for a question about CPU load, don't you think?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I added them again.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet (not enough rep) so I have no choice but to offer an answer.

In its time WinGroove was always a CPU hog - I assume the author purposefully coded it this way - that is, to exploit the CPU in ways unfriendly to other processes in order to maximize WinGroove's performance. In an era of slow CPUs, perhaps that approach made some sense. In my youth I used to code like that (I feel bad now for doing it, but I know I wasn't the only one).

Since you can't fix WinGroove, you can at least try to restrict it to a single CPU core via Task Manager. Like this:

[How to restrict a process to certain CPU cores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAdmZ.png)

*Screenshot obtained [from Windows 8 Forums](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/cpu-affinity-shortcut-for-a-program-create-in-windows.40339/).*